# Android layout solution

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make layout comparable for both phones and tablets. Since there is so many different screen sizes and resolutions I am wondering what is the best way to achieve something like shown bellow.

[image]

Bottom banner should retain aspect ratio but still fill 100% width of screen.
As of logo, image and buttons they need to be as close as possible like shown on all devices.

Can anybody point me what is the proper solution for this (relative/linear) layout or there is a different approach?

Sorry if this question is not suitable nut I am struggling for few hours finding the best way to display correctly. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own Star view programatically and use it as a background,

```
public class StarLayout extends RelativeLayout {


 public StarLayout(Context context) {
  super(context);
 }

 public StarLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
 }

 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
 public StarLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
  super(context, attrs, defStyle);

 }



 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

  Path clipPath = new Path();
  clipPath.addPath(Star());
  canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
  canvas.drawColor(Color.MAGENTA);

  super.onDraw(canvas);

 }


 private Path Star() {

  Path path = new Path();
  float midX = getWidth()/2;
  float midY = getHeight()/2;

  path.moveTo(midX, midY);
  path.lineTo(midX+190, midY+300);
  path.lineTo(midX, midY+210);
  path.lineTo(midX-190, midY+300);
  path.lineTo(midX-160, midY+90);
  path.lineTo(midX-300, midY-70);
  path.lineTo(midX-100 ,midY-110);
  path.lineTo(midX, midY-300);
  path.lineTo(midX+100, midY-110);
  path.lineTo(midX+300, midY-70);
  path.lineTo(midX+160, midY+90);
  path.lineTo(midX+190, midY+300);

  return path;

 }
```

To use it as a backgroud,

```
 <com.example.StarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#b4b4b4"

    >
```

Original source:

http://balvinder788.blogspot.com/2015/01/star-shape-layout-designing-android.html

Answer (score 0):

What I would do have a parent LinearLayout (Vertical) Then have two LinearLayouts within that, one to hold the Logo, Image, and Buttons and another to hold the Banner. The two buttons should be in their own LinearLayout (Horizontal) within the first inner layout. The banner should have its own.

Make the first LinearLayout's height "wrap_content" and make the banner's LinearLayout height "fill_parent" and set the gravity to "bottom"

Quick drafted example below, just replace the Textview with your Logo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
        <TextView
            android:text="Your Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:gravity="center" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:gravity="center">
            <Button
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/button1" />
            <Button
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/button2" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```